# Сокращение кода String в if

Tags: java, android, textview

У меня имеется следующее "**meow** *(вопрос)* - **wow** *(ответ)*. И так далее"
Так вот, можно ли сократить данный код?

1) (**ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО**) Хочу использовать парсинг из (.txt/.html/.db) файла, который будет находиться в assets.
2) Или же использовать сокращение в `MainActivity.java`

```
 @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("meow")) textView.setText("wow");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("stack")) textView.setText("overflow");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("bang")) textView.setText("boom");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("hello")) textView.setText("bye");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("meow")) textView.setText("wow");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Не следует каждый раз вызывать `charSequence.toString()`, его можно вызвать один раз.
2. Не нужно столько `if`, можно использовать `switch-case`.

Получится следующее:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    switch (charSequence.toString()) {
        case "meow":
            textView.setText("wow");
            break;
        case "stack":
            textView.setText("overflow");
            break;
        case "bang":
            textView.setText("boom");
            break;
        case "hello":
            textView.setText("bye");
            break;
    }
}
```

Строки можно вынести в `final`-переменные, либо в ресурсы.

Также, как посоветовали в соседнем ответе, вопрос-ответ можно поместить в `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, String> baseMap = new HashMap<>();
baseMap.put("meow", "wow");
baseMap.put("stack", "overflow");
baseMap.put("bang", "boom");
baseMap.put("hello", "bye");
```

А затем просто получать значение по ключу:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String answer = baseMap.get(charSequence.toString());
    if (answer != null) {
        textView.setText(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Использование switch не во всех версиях будет работать, так что так не надо делать

Comment: @Twikoffin, Посмотрите с помощью отладчика в чем проблема.

Answer (score 4):

Не уверен, что точно вас понял.
Можно, например, сохранить список вопрос-ответ в ассоциативный массив, а в методе просто вытаскивать по ключу нужный текст и вставлять в textView;